# Videos: best compression for HQ videos

Tags: mobile, video, browser, video-streaming

I'm pretty new on this topic
In a project where I'm involved, my customer asked to me to indicate her the best size a video must have in order to be displayed both on a web browser and on a mobile device.
Her requirement is: which dimension must a video have in order to be of good quality and with a lenght of around 5 minutes?
So I guess this is not only related to the file dimension but also on the compression and on the quality of the file...so...my question is: what is the best compression and other things the file should have in order to be displaied both on a web browser and on a mobile device?

Thank you
Angelo